# Firebase Recyclerview indexed query is not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm trying to get collections of data from my followers.

So this is my followers structure

[image: Followers DB]

And this is for topics

[image: topics]

And I'm using the following code for recyclerview to get topics from those users..

```
firebaseOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Topic>()
                .setIndexedQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("followers").child("heymark"), FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("topics").child("all").getRef(), Topic.class)
                .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter2 = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Topic, ViewHolder>(firebaseOptions) {
            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.topic_card, parent, false);

                return new ViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position, Topic model) {
                holder.text.setText(model.getCaption());
            }


        };
        adapter2.startListening();
        topicFeed.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

But it's not working. It only showing two nodes from topics. But I want to access those topics not just names. So how can I do that.

Comment: Do you want only child nodes of `topics`

Comment: Nope I want to access L1WkAFcMVwRFhRSgSx3 from the example database @Heisen-Berg